# Running a python Apache Beam Pipeline on Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-beam

I am giving apache beam (with python sdk) a try here so I created a simple pipeline and I tried to deploy it on a Spark cluster.

```py
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
import apache_beam as beam

op = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=DirectRunner"
    ]
)


with beam.Pipeline(options=op) as p:
    p | beam.Create([1, 2, 3]) | beam.Map(lambda x: x+1) | beam.Map(print)
```

This pipeline is working well with DirectRunner. So to deploy the same code on Spark (as the portability is a key concept in Beam)...

First I edited the `PipelineOptions` as mentioned [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/):

```py
op = PipelineOptions([
        "--runner=PortableRunner",
        "--job_endpoint=localhost:8099",
        "--environment_type=LOOPBACK"
    ]
)
```

`job_endpoint` is the url to the docker container of the [beam spark job server](https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/beam_spark_job_server/tags) that I run using the command:

```sh
docker run --net=host apache/beam_spark_job_server:latest --spark-master-url=spark://SPARK_URL:SPARK_PORT
```

This is supposed to work well but the job fails on Spark with this error :

```
20/10/31 14:35:58 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.

java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.spark.deploy.ApplicationDescription; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 6543101073799644159, local class serialVersionUID = 1574364215946805297
```

Also, I have this WARN in the `beam_spark_job_server` logs:

```
WARN org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.SparkContextFactory: Creating a new Spark Context.
```

Any idea where is the problem here? Is there any other way to run python Beam Pipelines on spark without passing by a containerized service ?

Comment: Which Beam version are you using? And which Spark version is your Spark cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen due to a version mismatch between the version of the Spark client contained in the job server and the version of Spark to which you are submitting the job.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is not too late to answer the question. Yes, it is due to version mismatch. I tested and it only work for Spark 2 and does not version 3. If you need an example of running on Kubernetes, can refer to https://github.com/cometta/python-apache-beam-spark . If it is useful for you, can help me to 'Star' the repository. Feel free to create an issue on the repository, I will look into it.